# Why Play framework 2.5 does not use all connections in connection pool

Tags: java, playframework, threadpool, connection-pooling, playframework-2.5

I have setup a play 2.5 project with heavy database access using Ebean. i configure hikaricp to maximumPoolSize=100 and minimumIdle=100 and hikaricp pool 100 connection successfully and i also configure thread pool like this:

```
akka {
  actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      throughput = 1
      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 109 # db conn pool (100) + number of cores (8) + housekeeping (1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I implement async action using CompletionStage:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> asyncDb() {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<>().supplyAsync(() -> {
        Ebean.createSqlQuery("select sleep(3)").findUnique();
        return 0;
    });

    return future.thenApplyAsync(integer -> ok("done"));
}
```

I run system using sbt start and test it using apache benchmark:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 -r -k http://localhost:9000/asyncDb
```

The problem is play only use 7 or 8 connection from pool and other mysql connection are idle meanwhile there are request, why?

Answer (score 0):

`Greg Methvin` answered my question in [play google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/r6bOOX1ZDU0) :
I think the problem is that CompletableFuture.supplyAsync does not use the default dispatcher. It's instead using ForkJoinPool.commonPool(). (See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-))

You need to use [the version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) that accepts an executor

For the executor you actually have two options:

1. Pass the ActorSystem to your controller and call actorSystem.dispatcher(), and configure it as you did above, or
2. Create a separate executor with 100 threads specifically for your database, and keep the default executor for processing requests.

Check out [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#Best-practices) here for different options re thread pools: